# Why is MIN()/MAX() functions ignored in a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I need an explanation why MIN/MAX functions are ignored in a subquery. I have found nothing in documentation about met behavior.

for instance

There are 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE A(COL1 NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE B(COL1 NUMBER);
```

populated with data by the following PL/SQL block

```
SET TIMING ON
DECLARE
INSERT_STATEMENT VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN 
FOR I IN 1..100
LOOP
INSERT_STATEMENT := 'INSERT INTO A(COL1) VALUES(round(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,3)))';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE INSERT_STATEMENT;
INSERT_STATEMENT := 'INSERT INTO B(COL1) VALUES(round(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,2)))';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE INSERT_STATEMENT;
END LOOP;
commit;
END;
/
```

distribution of tables values

```
SELECT COL1,COUNT(COL1) COUNT# FROM A GROUP BY COL1;
SELECT COL1,COUNT(COL1) COUNT# FROM B GROUP BY COL1;


      COL1     COUNT#
---------- ----------
         1         26
         2         53
         3         21

SQL>
      COL1     COUNT#
---------- ----------
         1         50
         2         50
```

The "problem" queries are

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.COL1=(SELECT MIN(B.COL1) FROM B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1);

  COUNT(*)
----------
        79

SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.COL1=(SELECT MAX(B.COL1) FROM B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1);

  COUNT(*)
----------
        79

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |      |    67 |  2546 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER              |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY      |      |    67 |  2546 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN SEMI    |      |    67 |  2546 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |   100 |  2500 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |   100 |  1300 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("A"."COL1"=MIN("A"."COL1"))
   3 - access("A"."COL1"="B"."COL1")
```

Both queries return 79 rows from table A where values of table A exist in table B.

I'm a bit confused as I expected above query with MIN()/MAX() functions should return 26 and 53 rows respectively. But it looks like MIN/MAX functions are ignored in queries like those.

Working examples of expected results

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A A2 WHERE A2.COL1=(SELECT MIN(B.COL1) FROM A,B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1);

  COUNT(*)
----------
        26

SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A A2 WHERE A2.COL1=(SELECT MAX(B.COL1) FROM A,B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1);

  COUNT(*)
----------
        53
```

What I'm wondering is why the MIN/MAX functions are ignored in a subquery

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.COL1=(SELECT MIN(B.COL1) FROM B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1);
    
      COUNT(*)
    ----------
            79
    
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.COL1=(SELECT MAX(B.COL1) FROM B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1);
    
      COUNT(*)
    ----------
            79
```

Comment: WHERE A.COL1= A.COL1...

Comment: because your condition ensures that B.COL1 is equal to A.COL1, so taking the min or max of that is irrelevant, it's always the value of A.COL1.

Answer (score 5):

Your subquery

```
(SELECT MAX(B.COL1) FROM B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1)
```

is correlated against A, so for each value of `A.COL1`, if any rows exists in B with the same `COL1` value - which is true for 1 and 2, but not for 3 - then since `A.COL1=B.COL1`, `MAX(B.COL1)` also must equal `MAX(A.COL1)`. You can see in the predicate information that it's has translated to the equivalent:

```
   1 - filter("A"."COL1"=MIN("A"."COL1"))
   3 - access("A"."COL1"="B"."COL1")
```

And because of the correlation again, `A.COL1 = MIN(A.COL1)` is really just `A.COL1 = A.COL1`.

Another way of looking at it is that when there is a row in B you're *effectively* replacing the subquery result with:

```
WHERE A.COL1 = A.COL1
```

which is always true for the `COL1` values 1 and 2 and false for 3; and of there a no rows in B then for those it's effectively replaced with:

```
WHERE A.COl1 = null
```

which is never true.

Remove that correlation and it will do what you expected - as shown in [this db<fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NvxN8-4X), with different random data:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.COL1=(SELECT MIN(B.COL1) FROM B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1);
```

| COUNT(*) |
| --- |
| 76 |

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.COL1=(SELECT MAX(B.COL1) FROM B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1);
```

| COUNT(*) |
| --- |
| 76 |

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.COL1=(SELECT MIN(B.COL1) FROM B);
```

| COUNT(*) |
| --- |
| 24 |

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.COL1=(SELECT MAX(B.COL1) FROM B);
```

| COUNT(*) |
| --- |
| 52 |

Comment: `WHERE A.COL1 = A.COL1` shouldn't it be `WHERE A.COL1 = B.COL1` ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos - no, because I'm illustrating (not very clearly it seems) what the subquery evaluates to, depending on whether a row exists in B or not... There is no join in the main query, and I was trying not to actually introduce an `exists()` clause instead. I've reworded slightly, not sure that helps much.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I asked mainly because "which is always true for the COL1 values 1 and 2 and false for 3" as `a.col1=a.col1` could never be false.

Comment: Right... it was preceded by "when there is a row in B" but, yeah, it's still not entirely clear, is it *8-)

Answer (score 4):

Because your condition ensures that `B.COL1` is equal to `A.COL1`, so taking the `min` or `max` of that is irrelevant, it's always the value of `A.COL1`. I think you may want these queries to get the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.COL1=(SELECT MIN(B.COL1) FROM B);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.COL1=(SELECT MAX(B.COL1) FROM B);
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.COL1=(SELECT MIN(B.COL1) FROM B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1);
```

Is finding rows from `A` where `B` also has a matching `col1` row (the outer-query correlates with the inner query so when `A.col1 = 1` then `B.col1` must also equal `1`, if any such row exists, and then `MIN(B.col1)` also equals `1`; similarly for `2` and `3`, although rows in `B` only exist for values `1` and `2`, not `3`).

It is effectively the same as:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1);
```

Since table `B` only contains the values `1` and `2` then the count of the values in table `A` will only be of the `1` and `2` values but not the `3` values, which gives the value 79.

---

If you add a `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   A
WHERE  A.COL1=(SELECT MIN(B.COL1) FROM B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1)
GROUP BY a.col1;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   A
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1)
GROUP BY col1;
```

Then both queries output:

| COL1 | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 26 |
| 2 | 53 |

As you will be counting for each `A.col1` (rather than counting the total of all `A.col1` values).

---

Your successful query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   A A2
WHERE  A2.COL1=(SELECT MIN(B.COL1) FROM A,B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1);
```

Is inner joining `A` and `B` and is correlating that `A2.COL1=MIN(B.COL1)` after the aggregation (whereas the previous query was correlating before aggregation).

You could equivalently write the final query as:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   A A2
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   B
         WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1)
         HAVING A2.COL1=MIN(B.COL1)
       );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yC1bWUha)